# Positive integer solutions to $x^4+y^7=z^9$

Tags: diophantine-equations

A while ago, a maths teacher gave me this problem: find solutions to $x^4+y^7=z^9$ with $x,y,z>0$. I found $(2^{56})^4+(2^{32})^7=(2^{25})^9$. In general, if $k=8+9l$ then $(2^{7k},2^{4k},2^{\frac{28k+1}{9}})$ is a solution. Then the teacher asked me two questions: are there any other solutions, and are there any other solutions where at least one of $(x,y,z)$ is odd.

My progress for the second question: it's easy to see that if at least one is odd, exactly two are odd. If $x$ and $z$ are odd, $1+0\equiv(2k+1)^9 (\text{mod }16)$, and similar equations exist for $(x,y)$ or $(y,z)$ are odd. Also, I've bruteforced this equation for $y\leq15000$ and $z<y$, but I wasn't able to find any solutions.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: of course, for any number n, we can find solutions such that $x,y,z\equiv 0  \text{ (mod n)}$, by multiplying $x^4+y^7=z^9$ with $n^{\text{lcm}(4,7,9)}$.
Also, my teacher gave the hint about the question about odd solutions: $1+511=512$.

Comment: Are you allowing negative numbers among the solutions?  (It's reasonably clear you don't consider $(1,0,1)$ to be a solution!)

Comment: No, it's just about positive numbers.

Comment: I edited the title to make that clear

Comment: What makes this question likely to be hard is the fact that there _are_ solutions, meaning that considering the equation modulo some numbers can never exclude further solutions, unless one starts to investigate deeper arithmetic information about the numbers (which I don't expect given the complexity of the equation).

Comment: $1/4 + 1/7 + 1/9 < 1$. In [their 1994 paper](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/12.Granville/paper.pdf), Darmon and Granville has shown that if $1/p + 1/q + 1/r < 1$ then for $A, B, C$ nonzero integers, $Ax^p + Bx^q = Cx^z$ has finitely many primitive solutions. So the equation has only finitely many primitive solution as a consequence. [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882756/diophantine-equation-np3p-k2/882929#comment1822186_882929) a heuristic reason for this.

Comment: See [Beal's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal's_conjecture).

Comment: Take that $1+511=512$ and multiply through by $511^k$ for a clever choice of $k$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that $(x^4:y^7:z^9)$ is the simple ratio $(48:1:49)$. I basically started from that and looked for $N$ such that $48N,N,49N$ are respectively 4th, 7th, and 9th powers. This is basically what **Gerry Myerson** suggested in spelling out your teacher's hint, except that $48+1=49$ yields a somewhat simpler solution than $1+511=512$. (What makes these ratios work is that $48/24$ and $512/29$ are odd integers.)

Thus, a solution with $y,z$ odd is:

$$
(x,y,z) = (2 \! \cdot \! 3^{16} \! \cdot \! 7^{49}, 3^9 \! \cdot \! 7^{28}, 3^7 \! \cdot \! 7^{22})
$$

There are similar solutions with $x,z$ or $x,y$ odd.